# Needed laravel model relationship for two level back data fetch

Tags: laravel

I have three tables :

User :
id(pk),name

Seller:
id(pk),user_id(fk on user.id)

Balance:
id,seller_id(fk on seller.id)

I am returning Balance detail of each seller in datatable by hitting an API of BalanceController@index which is using Balance model to get balance table data.

How can I get user's name in this case?
Any relationship exists for two level back of belongsTo ? or any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the hasThrough relationship.

> The "has-one-through" relationship links models through a single intermediate relation.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through

Answer (score -1):

The relationship in Seller model

class Seller extends Model
{

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

}

The relationship in Balance model
class Balance extends Model
{

```
public function seller()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Seller','seller_id');
}
```

}

to get the User name

$user_name= $balance->seller->user->name;